# Windows Live / Hotmail retrieve Contacts' Emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, live, hotmail

after I did some research on the subject, I found that Windows Live stopped providing email addresses for a user's contacts through its API. Instead, they provide the email hashes.

I did a little more research, and i found **many** websites being able to retrieve the contact list for a user and displaying it (with emails, not hashes) but the difference is that i don't think they are using oAuth since to retrieve the emails, the user must provide his email/password.

I need to implement importing a user's contact list on my site and i see no workaround to doing it using oAuth REST requests through Live's API (granted that i was being able to get the access token and make other REST requests).

If not using oAuth, what are other ways of getting a Windows Live/Hotmail contact list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [Windows Live ID's Delegated Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287637.aspx). Even tho it's deprecated it'll have to do until i find a more effective solution.